# Using plotly.js animation feature

Tags: javascript, plotly

Yesterday Plotly release the new feature animation!!! So I was very eager to test this out, and with the current lack of documentations (temporary I suppose) I'm struggling quite a bit on how to use it. 
I did have a peek into the code on GitHub, but ... not working.

1. I define my div element in the template:

   ```
   <div id="plotDiv"> </div>
   ```
2. I wanted to have the plot responsive to resize events, thus I followed the example on the plotly website:

   ```
   const d3 = Plotly.d3;
   const gd3 = d3.select("#plotDiv")
      .style({width: "95%", "margin-left": "2.5%"});
   const gd = gd3.node();
   ```
3. Then generate the data (bits of angular magic and other things) but in the end it looks like this:

   ```
   data = {x: [array_ot_dates], y: [array_of_not_so_random_values], type:'bar'};
   ```
4. According to the jsdocs for the animation function, you need to pass a frame:

   ```
   let plotlyFrame = {data:data, layout:{}};
   ```
5. Try to call animation!!!

   ```
   Plotly.animate(gd, plotlyFrame);
   ```

And there it goes Kaboum!

First error is: *This element is not a Plotly plot: [object HTMLDivElement]*
But when I try this:

```
Plotly.newPlot(gd, data, {});
```

I have my plot...

So I tried to "predefine" gd by calling Plotly.plot with empty data and then the animate function...

```
Plotly.plot(gd, [], {});
// make my data not empty
Plotly.animate(gd, plotlyFrame);
```

And then I get the following error:

*plotly.js:116922 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_module' of undefined(…)*

Possibly the second could come from the fact I'm using angular and thus calling the function at one point 3 times in a close row.

Any advices? Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the person who worked on the animation feature! First of all, you can find the documentation here.

Regarding your specific question, it looks like the answer is that you need to initialize the plot before you animate it (I'll add this to the documentation!). For example:

```js
var frame = [{
  data: {
    y: [...new values...]
  }
}]

Plotly.plot(gd, [{x: [...], y: [...]}]).then(function() {
  Plotly.animate(gd, frame)
});
```

If some sort of user input is triggering the animation, the promise probably isn't necessary (since the input event will handle things and is pretty unlikely to get fired before `Plotly.plot` has had a chance to initialize).

Additionally, at the very least I believe you'll need to actually initialize the plot *with the trace you wish to animate*. I think you can probably get away with empty data, but you'll still need to at least have a trace defined, e.g. `Plotly.plot(gd, [{x: [], y: []}])`. I think the issue with your attempted fix is that `[]` for a list of traces is still empty as far as Plotly is concerned since that tells it nothing about the type of trace that exists. Also FYI, one thing the feature is *not* really designed to do is to draw the initial plot in a fancy manner. That could likely be accomplished, but it's not automatic given `animate` on an empty plot.

I hope that's enough to clarify issues! It was a pretty large feature, so we'd love feedback and to hear about successes/failures with it!

Comment: Do you have similar examples on your site because it is really helpful to understand easily how plotly works.

Comment: @oro777 Can you clarify what you mean? On the plot.ly/javascript/ site? There are lots of examples there and the link to the forthcoming animation documentation I posted in this answer should be live in a hopefully not more than a day or two.

Comment: OK I see, I hope you will let the examples live in your codepen. On the plot.ly/javascript there are some examples but I just wanted to have several different sources of plotly examples :) Anyway I am looking forward the future of the animation feature in plotly.

Comment: Oh! Great for all the info!!! Thanks a lot!! 
I'll play a bit with it and hopefully all will be fine *finger crossed*

Great job btw for the animation PR, I was almost checking every day for 3 weeks when it would get merged!! So glad it got released!

Comment: Makes two of us! Currently working on cleaning up some loose ends and pushing the limits of what it can do! :) http://codepen.io/rsreusser/pen/GjoAJA

Comment: @Ricky  Additional question for you: how would you animate a bar chart? I have managed with you answer to animate the line chart the way I want, but the bar chart (ti's the same chart except in bar type) ... nope, remains very static and not moving...  though it passes from the same code. Ideas?

Comment: @Quath — non-scatter traces currently work with animations, but they update instantaneously. Now that there's a framework into which they fit, it's not prohibitively difficult to add element persistence and transitions to other chart types, but it hasn't been done yet. I just deployed the docs here: https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/ Refinements to come!

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if it's possible for Plot.ly to animate any time there is a change to a plot. Currently I'm using the Plotly.newPlot function to generate a new plot when my data changes. I'd like to be able to call that function and then call animate passing in an old version of the plot data and a new version and have it animate the graph to the new version. Is that possible?

Comment: For anyone else's reference it appears that you can't initialize animate on an empty plot and have it animate with the function. It's only intended to change data that already exists